# How can I highlight searched substring in a textarea?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create notes app and right now I am struggling with my search function where I want to highlight the word I am looking for.

The main problem is that I am trying to highlight text that is contained within an input tag.
Here I worked with `<textarea>` and setter it's value as a **JSX** component and when it renders I get.

```
export function EditNote({
  listOfNotes,
  setListOfNotes,
  saveInLocalStorage,
  getTimeOfEdit,
  highlighter,
  searchItem,
}) {
 
  const highlighterRegExp = new RegExp(`(${searchItem})`, "gi");

  const { noteId } = useParams();
  const [isSaved, setIsSaved] = useState(false);
  const [noteToEdit, setNoteToEdit] = useState(
    listOfNotes
      .filter((note) => {
        return note.id == noteId;
      })
      .pop()
  );
  const editTitleRef = useRef();
  const editContentRef = useRef();

  const handleSave = () => {
    const updateLastEditTime = { ...noteToEdit, lastEdit: getTimeOfEdit() };

    setListOfNotes((prevState) => {
      
      const replaceSavedNote = prevState.findIndex(
        (element) => element.id == noteToEdit.id
      );
      prevState.splice(replaceSavedNote, 1, updateLastEditTime);
    

      prevState.sort((a, b) => b.lastEdit - a.lastEdit);

      return prevState;
    });

    saveInLocalStorage(JSON.stringify(listOfNotes));
    setIsSaved(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    saveInLocalStorage(JSON.stringify(listOfNotes));
  }, [listOfNotes]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.commands}>
        <Link to="/" className={styles.backBtn}>
          <IoReturnUpBackOutline />
        </Link>

        <button onClick={handleSave} disabled={isSaved}>
          Save
        </button>
      </div>
      <section
        className={styles.noteContainer}
        onChange={() => {
          setIsSaved(false);
        }}
      >
        <input
          type="text"
          className={styles.insertTitle}
          placeholder="Write a title..."
          ref={editTitleRef}
          onChange={() => {
            setNoteToEdit((prevState) => {
              return { ...prevState, title: editTitleRef.current.value };
            });
          }}
          value={noteToEdit.title}
        />
      
        <textarea
          className={styles.insertContent}
          onChange={() => {
            setNoteToEdit((prevState) => {
              return { ...prevState, content: editContentRef.current.value };
            });
          }}
          name=""
          cols="10"
          rows="50"
          placeholder="Type your thoughts..."
          ref={editContentRef}
          value={noteToEdit.content
            .split(highlighterRegExp)
            .map((word, index) => {
              return (
                <Highlighter word={word} key={index} searchItem={searchItem} />
              );
            })}
        />
      </section>
      <p>
        {noteToEdit.content.split(highlighterRegExp).map((word, index) => {
          return (
            <Highlighter word={word} key={index} searchItem={searchItem} />
          );
        })}
      </p>
    </>
  );
}

export function Highlighter({ searchItem, word }) {
  return <>{word === searchItem ? <mark>{word}</mark> : word}</>;
}
```

My problem at `<textarea>` is that when I search for a word and finds a match it renders in that position instead of my highlighted word just an array `['',{},'']`, where the object in the middle is a `$$typeof;` Now I understand that these things happen because the value attribute asks for a string and I gave him a component, but I ran out of ideas how can I manage to highlight my searched words in an editable tag.

As an alternative, I tried changing my `<textarea>` with a paragraph tag and make `contentEditable='true'` but it acts way more weird when I try to edit my text, so I would like to stick with my first approach if possible. I also tried to work with mark.js library, but it wasn't of much help because in the end when I set the textarea value it will be every time a component that I'm giving. One thing I also tried was to control the node that replaced my word.

```
0:""1:
$$typeof:
Symbol(react.element)key: "1"
props:
{children: 'word'}
ref: null type: "mark" \_owner:
FiberNode {tag: 0, key: '0', stateNode: null, elementType: ƒ, type: ƒ, …}\_store: {validated: false}
\_self: undefined
\[\[Prototype\]\]: Object2: ""length: 3
```

But I couldn't find a proper way to access it.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. Also take the [tour].